# Connecting Named Instance in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

While connecting to a Remote SQL Server with two instance (Default, Named) I can easily connect to the default instance with the static IP but when its to Named Instance I can not connect through SSMS by putting "ServerName/InstanceName" rather then I can access by putting Port No like "ServerName,PortNo",  but I want to connect with the InstanceName.

Things I have tried are :

1. Disabled firewall
2. SQL Browser is running

Comment: Are you using `ServerName/InstanceName` or `ServerName\InstanceName`? Only the latter is valid.

Comment: Using Later one ! Mistyping

Answer (score 0):

Check the protocols for the named instance in SQL Server Configuration Manager. Make sure TCP/IP and its IP addres(ses) are enabled.

Comment: TCP/IP and IP addresses are enabled